# "Row is not JSON serializable" error when sending result set to a Flask view

Tags: json, sql-server, flask, pyodbc

I'm tryin to send the result of a pyodbc query to my view but i get a `TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable`.

Suppose I have a table like this in SQL Server:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1 | val2 |
| 2 | val3 | val4 |

I'm querying it through pyodbc and passing data to the view like this:

```
return render_template(
    'index.html'
    ,data={
        'foor':'bar'
        ,'rows':db.execute(
            'SELECT * '
            'FROM [' + table.schema_name + '].[' + table.table_name + ']'
        ).fetchall()
    }
)
```

If I print `{{ data.rows }}` I want to have `[[1,"val1","val2"],[2,"val3","val4"]]` but instead I get `[(Decimal('1'), 'val1', 'val2'), (Decimal('2'), 'val3', 'val4')]`.

If I `print(type(data.rows))` in the controller I obtain `<class 'list'>`.

Trying to convert it to JSON in the view with `{{ data.rows|tojson }}` results in `TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable`. How to achieve my need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns a list of `pyodbc.Row` objects. Row objects are similar to tuples but, as the error message states, they are not JSON serializable.

```py
results = crsr.execute(query).fetchall()
print(f"{type(results)} of type {type(results[0])}")
# <class 'list'> of type <class 'pyodbc.Row'>

json_string = json.dumps(results)
# TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable
```

We can convert the Row objects to true tuples so they can be serialized:

```py
results = [tuple(row) for row in results]
print(f"{type(results)} of type {type(results[0])}")
# <class 'list'> of type <class 'tuple'>

json_string = json.dumps(results)
# no error (unless the tuples themselves contain elements that are not serializable)
```

If the tuples do contain elements that are not serializable (like `Decimal` objects) then we can coerce them to string …

```py
json_string = json.dumps(results, default=str)
```

… or we can modify the query to CAST the decimals to floats, e.g., use

```py
query = "SELECT CAST(x AS FLOAT) AS x FROM tbl"
```

instead of

```py
query = "SELECT x FROM tbl"
```

Comment: this gives me `TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: thanks Gord, I found out that simplejson package handle those case natively...do you see any pros o cons using json package rather than simplejson package?

Comment: I've never used simplejson myself, so I can't really say. However, simplejson has been around for a very long time and is apparently still actively maintained.

Comment: For me, the associative keys are lost, only numeric keys remain. I'm using SQLite3 here and I set the row factory as follows: `connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row`.